# Google drive file upload and share it to public access

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api, public, google-api-php-client

I am uploading files to google drive account, what i want to do is to make it readable, but not editable to the public. How can i do that?

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->title = $_POST['name'];
$file->shared = "public"; //i need to do this
$file->folder = "/somefolder/"; // and this
```

[optional]

It's actually 3 in 1 question: I also want to place that file into a specific folder on a drive, and i whant to know how to create that folder on google drive.

Comment: Not sure if it's nicely built into the PHP lib, but you could get started by looking at the general API docs around permissions: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource , and I'm guessing you want 'type: "anyone"'

Answer (score 0):

**Might be useful for newbies:**

---

```
<?php
$client = new Google_Client();

// SET Client ID, Client Secret, Tokens as per your mechanism
?>
```

**Step 1:**

1. Create the folder. The API will return the ID for the folder created.

**Step 2:**

Upload the file in to the folder with `setParents([]);`

Example:

```
<?php
// Upload the file to efgh folder which is inside abcd folder which is in the root folder
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setParents(["abcd123", "efgh456"]); // abcd123 and efgh456 are IDs returned by API for the respective folders
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$service->files->create($file);
?>
$fileID = ""; // file ID returned by Drive.
```

**Step 3:**

Setting the permissions to shareable:

```
<?php
$permissionService = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$permissionService->role = "reader";
$permissionService->type = "anyone"; // anyone with the link can view the file
$service->permissions->create($fileID, $permissionService);
?>
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create